# ¿Cómo agregar un botón personalizado en un artículo que no tiene Stock?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy trabajando con `Wordpress` y `WooCommerce`, necesito agregar un **botón de contacto** si en mi tienda **algún producto se queda sin stock**, es decir:

> **Si el Stock es 0,  muéstreme un botón de contacto.**

En la siguiente imagen se ve más específico donde lo quiero insertar:

[image: ejemplo de lo que quiero agregar]

## EDIT:

He encontrado como añadir el botón, pero se añade a todo los productos, y solo quiero que aparezca el botón cuando no tengo stock en alguno de mis productos.
Aquí dejo el código utilizado:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'cs_additional_button');
function cs_additional_button() {
     echo '<button type="submit" class="button alt">contacto</button>';
}
```

**EDIT:**

El actual codigo me muestra el boton pero no como se desea.

[image: boton]

Answer (score 0):

Podrías obtener los meta datos del producto de la siguiente manera:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'cs_additional_button');
function cs_additional_button() {
    $IDProducto = get_the_ID();
    $stock =  get_post_meta($IDProducto ,'_stock',true); // Aquí le debes poner el nombre del meta que tiene el stock en la tabla
    if($stock == 0)
        echo '<button type="submit" class="button alt">contacto</button>';
}
```

El campo "_stock" se puede obtiene de la columna `meta_key` de la tabla `wp_postmeta`, que es donde se guardan todos los meta datos de las entradas. Con la función `get_post_meta()` se puede obtener el valor almacenado para dicha clave (en resumidas cuentas, te da el valor de la columna `meta_value`).

Espero haber sido claro y útil!

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda voy a probar, pero una pregunta , como se el nombre del meta que tiene mi stock en la tabla? donde puedo ir a mirar eso?

Comment: Podrías fijarte en la tabla `wp_postmeta`, ahí deberías fijarte en la columna `meta_key` si hay algo parecido al stock. Avisame si te funcionó por favor! Saludos!

Comment: lo mas parecido que encuentro en el `wp_postmeta` es `_products_id` no veo nada que me diga algo de stock, lo acabode probar con  `_products_id ` y no me funciona .

Comment: Estuve inventigando y encontré que el campo se llama `_stock` acá: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937555/echo-woocommerce-stock-quantity-of-a-particular-product-id

Comment: vale, estoy mirando la tabla y las demás tablas que contiene mi proyecto y no he encontrado ninguna que se llame `_stock` o algo similar :/, ya probe el codigo añadiendole `_stock` y aun nada, actualmente se muestra el  botón contacto pero al lado del botón añadir al carrito a los productos que si tienen stock.

Comment: Probaste con todas las respuestas de la pregunta que pasé? :S

Comment: Claro , es mas esa pregunta la tengo abierta en mi navegador he estado desde la mañana investigando como poner ese boton pero aun nada u_u

Comment: Lamento no haber sido de ayuda

Comment: Genarito gracias igualmente , seguiré investigando , esperare futuras respuestas y si encuentro la solución la posteare aquí, gracias igualmente, buen dia ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado:

Gracias por la ayuda ya encontré una solución que me sirve ami, espero les sirva a ustedes.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'boton_sub_producto_single', 6 );
function boton_sub_producto_single() {
        global $product;
            if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() || ! $product->is_purchasable() ){
                echo '<button type="submit" class="button alt" onclick="window.location.href=http://http://138.197.9.71/prov-individuales/">contacto</button>';
            }
            return $product;            
    }
```

Que hace esto? Bueno la función solo me indica si el producto no esta en stock y no se puede comprar algo así entonces muéstreme un botón.
La solución no la encontré, sino analice varias soluciones a problemas un tanto similares y fusione código obviamente usando la lógica.